# How do I format a US short code number for Twilio?

Tags: sms, twilio

I don't have access to a short code yet in my account. I'm wondering whether the short code should be given in the `From` parameter as e.g. `222333` or whether we should prepend `+1` as in `+1222333`.

I'm not sure whether E.164 applies to [short codes](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/short-codes).

Answer (score 1):

Twilio support says no `+1` is necessary.